# how to verify when RAM memory was update on RHEL machine

Tags: rhel, kernel, lvm, memory, ram

we have VM machines (machines are RHEL 7.9), and recently machines RAM memory was update from 32G to 64G

is it possible to verify on which date? memory was update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your kernel logs at boot should give you the total memory. Did you search through them?

See this previous post in [stack exchange](https://serverfault.com/questions/463175/historical-data-logs-on-what-ram-and-disk-storage-used-to-be-in-linux).

On my system, I kind of just shotgun with

`grep -i ram /var/log/*`

Bib in comments notes:

`grep -Ei memory.+available /var/log/*`

may work better. It does on my test cases.

But on RHEL it may well be /var/log/messages

Comment: `grep -Ei memory.+available /var/log/*` may be better.

Comment: Tested, yes, better on my box.